# JavaScript/jQuery Callback on("submit")

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, submit, alert

Can someone tell me why this script doesn't work.

I want the alert for "I just submitted the form" before "The form submitted." So I used a callback but it's still jumping past the submit.

```
function formSubmit(callback) {
    $("form").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("I just submitted the form.");
    });
    callback();
}

formSubmit( function() {
    alert("The form submitted.");
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/forTesting.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the callback after the alert, not after binding the `submit` handler.

```
function formSubmit(callback) {
    $("form").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("I just submitted the form.");
        callback();
    });   
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I just figured that out. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You must run your `callback` function within the jQuery event handler function (the second argument to `on`. Otherwise, `callback` will just execute immediately inside of `formSubmit`, but `alert("I just submitted the form.");` will only execute once the submit event occurs.

```js
function formSubmit(callback) {
    $("form").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("I just submitted the form.");
        callback();
    });
}

formSubmit( function() {
    alert("The form submitted.");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I figured it out just this morning and feel like a doofus.

Comment: @user37172 Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept an answer if you found it helpful.